# TwentyTwelve child theme: Incorrect footer menu

Tags: menus, theme-twenty-twelve

I built [a child theme of Twenty Twelve](http://brinkley.doig.com.au/), and created a menu called "Footer Menu" in Appearance > Menus.  I assigned this menu to the Footer location:
[image]

However, the footer menu in the live site displays the same menu as Primary Menu.

I have not changed footer.php:

```
<footer id="colophon" role="contentinfo">
    <div>
        <?php wp_nav_menu (array ('theme_location' => 'Footer', 'menu_class' => 'footer-menu' )); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="site-info">
        Copyright &copy; Brinkley & Chesnut
    </div><!-- .site-info -->
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

Why is the wrong menu displaying in the footer?

**Update**

functions.php contains:

```
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus (
        array ('footer-menu' => __ ('Footer'))
    );
}
```

I changed "Footer" to "footer" in both functions.php and footer.php, but the issue remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that the `theme_location` is "footer" not "Footer". It is case sensitive. I just checked. If you use a bad `theme_location` [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) will fallback to what looks like a page menu when I test it.

## Edit:

Due to additional information in the question, the `theme_location` is `footer-menu` and not `footer`. If you look at the [Codex page for `register_nav_menus`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus) you will see that it takes "An associative array of menu location slugs (key) and descriptions (according value." The array `key` is the menu location. That is the value you need.